# How to duplicate a string multiple times and add a random array value to it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to return the string 'street' 5 times and for it to add 4 random letters from the 'letters' array for each time so that they're different for each street.

```js
let letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

let a = {
    street: 'Street 21 ',
    do: function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.street += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];     
        };
    }
}
```

My code adds 4 random letters from the array to street already, but im not sure how to duplicate it multiple times, I can't just use .repeat() as I also need it to be in new lines.

Expected output:

```js
Street 21 JIDX
Street 21 UYXZ
Street 21 ABCD
Street 21 EFGH
Street 21 KLMN
```

Comment: @MichaelBianconi yes just added it

Comment: Is that output a string or array of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `map` and `join`. That's easier to read, IMHO, and more functional.

```js
const letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

const result = new Array(5)
  .fill('Street 21')
  .map(
    el =>
      el +
      ' ' +
      new Array(4)
        .fill('')
        .map(el => el + letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)])
        .join('')
  )
  .join('\n');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: And how can i make for each line it adds 3 random letters from the letters array instead of just one?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, didn't see that you needed three letters added.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want the output as a string:

```
let letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

let a = {
    street: 'Street 21 ',
    do: function() {
        var fullString = "";
        const multipleAmount = 5; // the amount of streets you want to generate.
        let streetString = this.street;

        for (let j = 0; j < multipleAmount; j++) {
           for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               streetString  += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];     
           };
           fullString += streetString;
           fullString += "\n"; // new line
           streetString = this.street;
        }
        this.street = fullString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried running that and this is the output i received:


Street 21 FStreet 21 AStreet 21 QStreet 21 Z
Street 21 ZStreet 21 IStreet 21 BStreet 21 K
Street 21 KStreet 21 IStreet 21 XStreet 21 J
Street 21 UStreet 21 TStreet 21 LStreet 21 B
Street 21 HStreet 21 QStreet 21 QStreet 21 T

5 lines of street 21 repeated 4 times in each line, not sure how to show it properly in comments

Comment: @vcosiekx my bad, fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const letters = [
  'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
  'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
];

const street = 'Street 21 ';

function generateRandomLetter() {
  return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
}

function generateNRandomLetters(n) {
  return Array(n)
    .fill()
    .map(generateRandomLetter)
    .reduce((s, l) => `${s}${l}`,'');
}

function generateResult() {
  const getStreetValue = () => `${street}${generateNRandomLetters(4)}`       

  return Array(4)
   .fill()
   .map(getStreetValue)
   .reduce((r, s) => `${r}\n${s}`, getStreetValue());
}

const result = generateResult();

console.log(result);
```